# Recursive array population with references works differently than manually populated version of the same script

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, reference

I'd like to wrirte a simple `php` script that creates tree-like structure. Here is my first, very basic, rude attempt:

```
<?php

$sKey = "key_1";
$sVal = "val_1";
$d = $sVal;
$arr = array();
$i = 0;

$arr[$sKey] = array($sKey."_1" => $sVal."_1");

$ptr = &$arr[$sKey];
print_r($ptr );

$sKey.="_1";
$sVal.="_1";
$ptr[$sKey] = array($sKey."_1" => $sVal."_1");
$ptr = &$ptr[$sKey];
print_r($ptr );

$sKey.="_1";
$sVal.="_1";
$ptr[$sKey] = array($sKey."_1" => $sVal."_1");
$ptr = &$ptr[$sKey];
print_r($ptr );

echo "---------\n";
print_r($arr );
```

and here goes an recursion - like approach

```
<?php

$sKey = "key_1";
$sVal = "val_1";
$d = $sVal;
$arr = array();
$i = 3;

$arr[$sKey] = array($sKey."_1" => $sVal."_1");

$ptr = &$arr[$sKey];
print_r($ptr );

function fun(){
    
    global  $ptr, $sKey, $sVal, $i;
    
    if($i-- != 0) {
        $sKey.="_1";
        $sVal.="_1";
        $ptr[$sKey] = array($sKey."_1" => $sVal."_1");
        $ptr = &$ptr[$sKey];
        print_r($ptr);
        fun();
    }
}

fun();

echo "---------\n";
print_r($arr );
```

My question is why the first version do work - it creates nested array while the second version (recursion) doesn't work - it creates just a flat array. The code in the function is exacly the same as in repeated code in my first version...

Comment: You should try and not use `global`.

Comment: @NigelRen Sure, but that is not the question here. The OP tries to understand references in PHP in combination with recursion.

Comment: The recursion works fine if you hand over `$ptr` as a reference argument to `fun(&$ptr)`, which indeed would be the normal pattern for a recursion algorithm. My stomach says that the repeated `global $ptr` remaps `$ptr` to the initial value, not the one assigned on the function. Interesting indeed...

Comment: @arkascha it is the cause of the problem as well as bad practice!

Comment: @NigelRen If you want to point it out as "the cause" then you should also explain _why_ that is the case...